EFPlus System.InvalidOperationException: Part does not exist
I am trying to develop and wpf application with selenium for learning purpouse, but i am facing someting strange. I want to use EFPlus to modify an Excel row at each itteration, on some computers works just fine, but also on another computers i get :
Nu s-a putut modifica EXCELUL cu SENT pentru id 3164092 + System.InvalidOperationException: Error saving file C:\WPFSElenium\ExcelFolder\test.xlsx ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Part does not exist.
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage.GetPart(Uri partUri)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage.DeletePart(Uri Uri)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.SaveDrawings()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()
   at WPFSElenium.MainWindow.<WaitForConfirmation>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\WPFSElenium\WPFSElenium\WPFSElenium\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 478

the code:
            confirmEvent
            
            private async void WaitForConfirmation()
                {
            confirmEvent.WaitOne();
            string chatId = "xxxxxxxxx";
            int controBlocareCont = 0;
            int idNegasiteConcomitent = 0;

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (Application.Current.MainWindow != null)
                {
                    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                }
            });
            Thread.Sleep(GenerateRandomInterval());
            
            string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ExcelFolder");
            if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                string[] excelFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.xlsx");
                if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    string filePath = excelFiles[0];

                    // Add full permissions to the Excel file
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                    FileSecurity fileSecurity = fileInfo.GetAccessControl();
                    fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                    fileInfo.SetAccessControl(fileSecurity);

                    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filePath)))
                    {
                        ExcelWorkbook workbook = package.Workbook;
                        if (workbook != null)
                        {
                            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
                            int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                            worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = false;

                            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
                            {
                                if (worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value == null)
                                {
                                    string id = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value?.ToString();
                                    if (id != null && (id.Length != 2 && id.Length != 1))
                                    {
                                       
                                        Thread.Sleep(GenerateRandomInterval());
                                        try
                                        {
                                                divElement.Text = "Test";
                                            string NumePersoana = divElement.Text;

                                            if (NumePersoana == worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString())
                                            {
                                                divElement.Click();

                                                ExcelWorksheet worksheetMesaje = workbook.Worksheets[1];
                                                int rowCountMesaje = worksheetMesaje.Dimension.End.Row;
                                                Random random = new Random();
                                                int randomRow = random.Next(2, rowCountMesaje + 1);
                                                string mesajAleatoriu = worksheetMesaje.Cells[randomRow, 1].Value.ToString();

                                                IWebElement textArea = null;
                                                try
                                                {
                                                    textArea = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("));
                                                    Thread.Sleep(GenerateRandomInterval());
                                                    textArea.SendKeys(mesajAleatoriu);
                                                    Thread.Sleep(GenerateRandomInterval());
                                                    textArea.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
                                                    Thread.Sleep(IntervalSendMessage);
                                                    worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = "Sent";
                                                    package.Save();
                                                    
                                                    InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                                                    InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                                                }
                                                catch (NoSuchElementException)
                                                {
                                                    worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = "Blocked";
                                                    package.Save();
                                                    InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                                                    InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                                catch (Exception ex)
                                                {
                                                    string messageSentErr = $"ATENTIE: Nu s-a putut modifica EXCELUL cu SENT pentru id {id} + {ex}";
                                                    InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                                                    InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                                                    await _botSender.SendMessageAsync(chatId, messageSentErr);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = "Not Sent";
                                                package.Save();
                                                InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                                                InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                                                controBlocareCont++;

                                                if (controBlocareCont == 10)
                                                {
                                                    string messageBlocked = "ATENTIE: Posibil sa aveti contul BLOCAT. \nVa rugam repornit BOT-ul cu un nou cont";
                                                    await _botSender.SendMessageAsync(chatId, messageBlocked);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (NoSuchElementException)
                                        {
                                            worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = "Not Sent";
                                            package.Save();
                                            InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                                            InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                                            idNegasiteConcomitent++;

                                            if (idNegasiteConcomitent % 10 == 0)
                                            {
                                                string messageElementNotFound = $"ATENTIE: {idNegasiteConcomitent} Id-uri nu a fost identificate la rand pe FACEBOOK \nVerificati corectitudinea fisierului EXCEL";
                                                await _botSender.SendMessageAsync(chatId, messageElementNotFound);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            string messageNotSentErr = $"ATENTIE: Nu s-a putut modifica EXCELUL cu NOT SENT pentru id {id} + {ex}";
                                            InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
                                            InputID.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
                                            await _botSender.SendMessageAsync(chatId, messageNotSentErr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            package.Save();
                            package.Dispose();
                            string message = "ATENTIE: Au fost procesate toate PERSOANELE din EXCEL-ul furnizat. \nVa rugam repornit BOT-ul cu un nou set de date";
                            await _botSender.SendMessageAsync(chatId, message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

the problem appear at package.Save();
i tried to do package.Dispose() after every excel modification , but at the second itteration i get another erroar that says the worksheet is disposed
